# Is this question about specific camera model possible to rescue or it's per definition off-topic?

Tags: discussion, equipment-recommendations

I'm choosing now new camera for me, and I have many doubts, especially because new Canon compact models are criticized because of too weak batteries and I have no experience with any other manufacturer.

I've asked a question about [Fujifilm HS30](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46918/fuji-hs30-exr-reasonable-choice-compared-to-canon-sx280), writing down my experience and my needs and asking if that camera would be reasonable choice for someone like me, and I've asked for clarifications of the rumours about poor picture quality (compared to concurrent companies).

This question was closed as shopping question, however, I disagree with that. I never asked if I should buy that camera or what should I buy. I asked about the parameters matching my needs and how the specific parameters are doing in real life in comparison with other companies. I think those things are quite good objectivised.

I'm aware that every site has its own culture and language, so the construction of argumentation and formulating of the questions must be very carefully adjusted for the specific needs of each site, especially if English is not my native language. Is the closing of that questions the result of misunderstanding because of formulation of the question? Can I do something with that question to made in opened and answered? Or are any questions targetting specific model condemned and there's nothing I can do to get the answer I need?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the original form of this question was perhaps mislabeled as shopping vs opinion based.  Photography and quality of a camera as it corresponds to your needs and value proposition are highly subjective and really isn't something that can be concretely determined by someone else.

If you wanted to know something like which has better low light performance, that is measurable, however "will it meet my expectations" is not.  How much does the price factor in to your expectations?  What is "good enough"?  These aren't objective measures.

I think Matt made a valiant attempt to salvage it and I do think he was headed in the right direction trying to steer you towards ways to help you make a judgement call for yourself, but it was probably still a little too awkward in its current form.

Fundamentally, only you can decide what meets or doesn't meet your expectations.  You are the one who has to live with your purchase and without very concrete measures of what your expectation is and what value you attribute to it, there is no way to objectively (or even meaningfully) say one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

is it only due to the battery rumours you wont get a canon? if so, you could ask about the battery issues.

Comment: I have already asked about batteries and I know that such battery life is unacceptable for me. I've just asked if specific camera gives image quality comparable to that from Canon cameras or it's significantly worse. The reviews from internet are contradicting. The arguments used by closer could be used for closing the question about the battery life of canon, anyway.

Comment: what I wonder is, if you have a compact that you are unhappy with the quality, already, why are you looking at a cheap lowend replacement, that you will also be unhappy with?

Comment: you should be considering the Canon G series or Panasonic Lumix LX7 if you are not ready to make the jump to DSLR.

Comment: and btw the battery life of sx280 is 3 times what you have now in your A530

Comment: since your old model is pre2009 (2006) you might experience an upgrade even if it is the lower end in IQ.

Comment: My A530 have costed about 120€ when I've bought it, and the replacements are over 2 times more expensive, so it's not replacing low-end with low-end. Low-ends costs now about 150€ and they are generally doing much much better photos then mine. I'd just like to choose something best from me from this middle-low end of price spectrum.

Comment: I saw it was 180$, pretty much 120E. However in EU you are right it is a bit more. like 200E. My compact was a sony "flagship" WX1 in 2009 that cost me 400E and the IQ is similar to my cellphone. very disappointing. Your thoughts show me that you have outgrown the "I just need to snap pictures" stage, so I think you've m outgrown the entry level compacts. At least go for one with RAW